# Big-Oh Notation

Tags: functions, programming, series-expansion

Is there a way to have Mathematica understand Big-Oh notation?

For example, I want something like:

```
MinBigOh[...]
```

where

```
MinBigOh[2x+3, x^2] = 2x+3
```

or

```
MinBigOh[2x+3, x^2] = x
```

The idea here is that I want to be able to augment "Min" to understand Big-Oh comparisons.

The purpose of this is so that I can write a bunch of expressions, and have Mathematica reason about the Big-Oh running time somewhat.

Thanks!

Comment: **And have Mathematica reason about the Big-Oh running time somewhat** is the hard part :D

Comment: If everything is polynomial you might get away with minBigOh[p1_, plist_List] := PolynomialReduce[p1, plist][[2]] (which is in keeping with the "term-rewritica" moniker).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following, which uses the built-in `O[x]^n` notation to denote a term of order $x^n$.

```
Clear[BigO]
BigO[expr_List, var_Symbol, func_] := 
     O[var]^func[Exponent[# - Coefficient[#, var, 0], var, func] & /@ expr]
```

Some examples:

```
BigO[{2 x + 3, x^2 + x^3}, x, Max]
(* O[x]^3 *)

BigO[{2 x + 3, x^2 + x^3}, x, Min]
(* O[x]^1 *)
```

If you only want to find the smallest order in the list of expressions, you can also use the fact that `O` automatically does `O[x]^n + O[x]^m == O[x]^n` when `n ≤ m` to write something like:

```
Clear[MinBigO]
MinBigO[expr_List, var_Symbol] := 
    Plus @@ Thread[O[var]^Exponent[# - Coefficient[#, var, 0], var, Min] & /@ expr]
```

Another example:

```
MinBigO[{2 x + 3, x^2 + x^3}, x]
(* O[x]^1 *)
```

Comment: But what about $O(n \cdot log(n))$ etc...?

Comment: @Brett Yes, that's harder... trying to think of something.

Comment: Isn't there some simple validity to the method I propose?  When does it fail?

Comment: @mr.wizard not near mma now, but I would say something like `MinBigOh[10 x, 1/10^6 x^2]` would fail for the specific answer. Of course, then you pick a bigger value to substitue, but you can always twiddle the coefficients to find a counter example and eventually you hit max/min machine number at which point you can no longer substitute. The objective is not whether which has a higher tunning time, but what the time complexity is.

Comment: I've never seen O notation in that form/degree before.  Some reading is in order I guess.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: the problem is that for some theoretical algorithms in CS, they have _terrible_ coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

Since 11.3 a range of Asymptotic based functions are available.

See: https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/07/26/big-o-and-friends-tales-of-the-big-the-small-and-every-scale-in-between/

Your

```
MinBigOh[2x+3, x^2]
```

could be implemented as

```
AsymptoticLessEqual[2 x + 3, x^2, x -> Infinity]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is sufficient to substitute a suitably large value for `x` and take the smallest?

```
MinBigOh[expr__] := SortBy[{expr}, # /. x -> 1`*^6 &][[1]]

MinBigOh[2 x + 3, x^2]
```

> ```
> 3 + 2 x
> ```

If you do this it would be prudent to use Formal Symbols e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$x`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
MinBigOh[var_, expr1_, expr2_]:=
  If[Limit[expr1/expr2, var->Infinity]==0, expr1, expr2]
```

Then you get

```
MinBigOh[x, 2x+3, x^2]
(*
==> 3 + 2 x
*)
MinBigOh[x, x, Log[x]]
(*
==> Log[x]
*)
```