# Asymptotic Rate of Growth

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I calculate the Asymptotic Rate of growth of a function, for instance like:

$X^3 - X^2 - X -1$

EDIT:

For instance, as you can see in this graph, after the 1200 the function approximates to the limit. I want to if there is a easy way to calculate the rate of grow, after 1200 for instance.

[image]

**Edit**

I'm trying to find a generalized way in order to graphically find it for Fibonacci, Tribonacci, Tetranacci sequences

Comment: Isn't it O(x^3)?

Comment: Are you asking for a generalized way of determining which term, e.g. x^3, x^2, x, or 1 grows fastest as x increases?

Comment: For polynomials, [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8181/5) or [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9970/5) might be what you're looking for. Possible duplicate

Comment: I'm trying to find a generalized way in order to graphically find it for fibonacci, tribonacci, tetranacci sequences

Comment: It doesn't happen all of a sudden at 1200... it's just that the plot range is such that it _seems_ it is that way. As a hint, look at `LogPlot[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 1500}]`

Comment: Related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47140/characteristic-polynomials-for-k-bonacci-numbers-whats-their-name

Comment: All the [$n$-nacci sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html) have exponential behavior; the base of their dominant exponential term is (expressed in *Mathematica* notation) `Root[x^n - Sum[x^k, {k, 0, n - 1}], Mod[n, 2, 1]]`.

Answer (score 3):

As J.M. mentioned in the comments:

All the [n-nacci sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html) have exponential behavior; the base of their dominant exponential term is (expressed in Mathematica notation)

```
Root[x^n - Sum[x^k, {k, 0, n - 1}], Mod[n, 2, 1]]
```

Demonstration:

```
With[{n = 2},
 base = Root[x^n - Sum[x^k, {k, 0, n - 1}], Mod[n, 2, 1]] // N;
 DiscretePlot[Fibonacci[x]/base^x, {x, 1, 40}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.7}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Daniel Lichtblau adds that Mathematica is able to calculate the Fibonacci series development at infinity:

```
Simplify[Normal[Series[FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[x]], {x,Infinity,2}]], 
         Assumptions->Element[x,Integers]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could take the series at infinity for cases like Fibonacci, where we have a closed form. This gives some exponential stuff: `Simplify[Normal[Series[FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[x]], {x,Infinity,2}]], Assumptions->Element[x,Integers]]`

Comment: PS Thanks for taking so much time to respond to several unanswered posts. I noticed you've handled quite a few in the past day or two. (Maybe others before that, but I wasn't noticing then.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! I had some spare time which coincided nicely with rm-rf's clean-up call.