# Sorting list with variable

Tags: sorting

I want to sort (or sortby) the list. List contains uninitialized variable m and I can assume that `m` is a Natural number that is much larger then any constant.

Example input:

```
a = {-116*m, 0, 3 - 11*m, 1 - m, -20*m - 7, -m}
```

Example output:

```
{-116*m, -20*m - 7, 3 - 11*m, -m, 1 - m, 0}
```

My effort:

```
MAGICNUMBER = 1000000;
Sort[a, (#1 /. m -> MAGICNUMBER) < (#2 /. m -> MAGICNUMBER) &]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8177/121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your own method seems fairly effective but it can be simplified:

```
a = {-116*m, 0, 3 - 11*m, 1 - m, -20*m - 7, -m};

SortBy[a, # /. m -> 1`*^12 &]
```

> ```
> {-116 m, -7 - 20 m, 3 - 11 m, -m, 1 - m, 0}
> ```

```
a[[ Ordering[a /. m -> 1`*^12] ]]
```

> ```
> {-116 m, -7 - 20 m, 3 - 11 m, -m, 1 - m, 0}
> ```

These methods will also perform much better than your use of `Sort` because the default sort algorithm is used rather than custom pairwise ordering.

Answer (score 3):

For your example input, which happens to be a list with elements in which `m` appears up to linearly, you can simply do this:

```
lst = {-116*m, 0, 3 - 11*m, 1 - m, -20*m - 7, -m};
lst[[Ordering[D[lst, m]]]]
(*{-116 m, -7 - 20 m, 3 - 11 m, 1 - m, -m, 0}*)
```

which basically gets rid of each term that does not contain `m`, then orders the rest according to the coefficient of `m`.

If you have things like `m^2` though this needs a bit more work.

Comment: 'm' appears linearly, therefore it is possible to take derivative. However would that not mean that constant elements would be in random order?

Comment: @Margus yes that's true, constant elements will remain in the order they are.

Comment: Well, then `Sort[lst][[Ordering[D[Sort[lst], m]]]]` would work.

Comment: Yes that's much better than what I was coming up with. Is it OK if I add it to the answer (with credit)?