# Determining if a function is asymptotic to another (big O notation)

Tags: functions, series-expansion

Is anyone familiar with using Mathematica to determine whether a function is asymptotic (big O) to another.

> A function $f$ is asymptotic to function $g$ if there are positive $c, n0$ such that $|f(n)| ≤ c|g(n)|$, for all $n ≥ n0$. This relationship is written $f(n) ∈ O(g(n))$.

#### Example

Determine whether the function $f(x) = 17x + 11$ satisfies $f(x) ∈ O(x^2)$.

My solution is `True`, because the determining factor in $f(x)$ is less than or equal to x^2.

I would like to use Mathematica to check my answer. How can I do that?

Comment: What is $g(x)$?

Comment: @CaelHo, it may be helpful [8177](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/big-oh-notation)

Answer (score 2):

(As long as your functions are analytical at the point of comparison), you can use the `Series` command

```
Series[f[x]/g[x],{x,x0,0}]
```

If this is `O[1]` our smaller than f[x] is O[g[x]] (at `x0`).

In your example, (presuming this is asked at infinity)

```
Series[(17x+11)/x^2,{x,\[Infinity],0}]
```

returns

```
17/x + O[1/x]^2
```

and hence is O[1/x]. Consequently, 17x+11 is O[x].